# Confusion regarding user authentication in OAuth2 flow: Where to verify user credentials?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, oauth, jwt, authorization

I'm developing a web application where I need to implement an authentication system using OAuth2. However, I'm a bit confused about how this new OAuth2 authentication service should work.

Obs: I'm developing this service in Node.js.

My current authentication service receives a username and password, and if they are valid (and are in my Users table), an access token is generated and returned to my client.

---

The new service I'm creating has a route for authorization (/authorize), generating a code_auth for my client.
Request to /authorize:

Method: GET
URL: http://localhost:3013/authorize?scope=read&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3014

---

After that, I have the route to obtain the token (/token), which receives the auth_code and returns the access_token.
Request to /token:

Method: POST
URL: http://localhost:3007/token
Request body:

```
{ 
   "authorization_code": "CODE_AUTH", 
   "client_id": "CLIENT_ID", 
   "client_secret": "CLIENT_SECRET" 
}
```

---

But since I'm new to OAuth2.0, I'm having trouble understanding where in this flow the verification of username and password that my previous service did fits in. Where in OAuth2 do I check if my user is a valid user? Is it in the /token route by passing the username and password along with the auth_code, or is it not correct to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your new service (the authorization server), should perform user authentication as part of the first request to the `/authorize` endpoint. This does not mean that you have to send the username and password together with that request. Usually, this works something like this:

1. You send a request to the `/authorize` endpoint. The browser will send any session cookies together with this request.
2. Your server checks the session cookies. Let's assume that the cookie is not there yet. Then the server responds with an HTML page that shows a form for login.
3. You enter the username and password and submit the form. It can be submitted to any URL, e.g. `/authenticate`.
4. The server validates username and password. If it's correct it generates an authorization code, saves it and sends back a redirect response that also sets a session cookie. So you will get something like this:

```http
HTTP 303
Set-Cookie: session_id=1234abcd
Location: http://localhost:3014?code=aaabbb
```

The browser will save the cookie and redirect the user to your callback with the authorization code. You can now exchange the code for an access token.

On subsequent login attempts, your browser will send the session cookie, so in point 2 you will get the response from point 4, without the need to reauthenticate again (as long as the session is valid on the server side, that is).

This approach also gives you good room for improving authentication. Between points 2 and response from point 4, you can easily add more authentication behaviours. E.g. you can ask the user for a 2-step authentication code, or you can start with presenting different authentication methods, e.g.: log in with Google, log in with Facebook, log in with your username and password, log in with passkeys, etc.

Comment: Nice, thank you very much for your detailed response! I will definitely try to implement the structure you suggested for user authentication in my OAuth2 authentication service.